# Eclipse CDT Link Options -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ Not Affecting Behavior on Windows

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, eclipse-cdt, mingw32

I'm a Java programmer but I'm teaching myself some C++ for a project I have to do (JNI).  To that end I have written a very simple DLL with a very simple DLL test program in C++ using Eclipse and MinGW GCC.  When trying to run the test program on Windows 7 (and any other version I have around) I got an error the libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll missing.  After reading some other questions on SO I found out about the -static-libgcc and -static-libstdc++ linker options which I added to the project settings.  The file sizes of the DLL and exe were very small before I added the static options and after adding them the DLL and exe were much larger, leading me to believe that the DLL's were actually getting included.  However, I'm still getting the missing DLL errors when trying to run the program.  If I copy the DLL's to the same folder as the exe then it runs.  i read some suggestions saying that one should just distribute the DLL's separately but that is far from ideal and I'd like to avoid it if possible.

I also tried just using the -static linker option but for some reason when I do that then the compiler can't find my simple DLL.  If I remove -static it can find it again just fine.  I'm not sure what that's about but maybe it's related to the overall issue?

I've read just about everything I could find on this topic and it seems that I'm doing the right thing, and that the DLL's are getting statically linked to the exe, but it's not having an effect at run time.  I'm at my wits end.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Pablo

**UPDATE 1**
I guess I wasn't totally clear.  The issue is that Windows is saying the C libraries are missing even though I'm linking them statically.  When I run a build these are the compile and linker commands being run:

```
g++ "-IC:\\_projects_eclipse\\bcsdll\\src\\" "-includeC:\\_projects_eclipse\\bcsdll\\src\\bcsdll.h" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o Main.o "..\\Main.cpp" 
g++ "-LC:\\_projects_eclipse\\bcsdll\\Debug" -Wl,-enable-stdcall-fixup -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o bcsdll_tester.exe Main.o -lbcsdll
```

The issue is that even though I'm including both C libraries statically when I run the EXE I still get a missing DLL error for the C libraries.  When I check the EXE and DLL with Dependency Walker it clearly shows no dependency on the two C libraries.  Yet still, when I run the EXE windows says the C++ library is missing.  If I put copies of the libraries in the same folder with my DLL and EXE then the program runs fine.

The actual missing DLL is libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll.  If I place a copy of that DLL in the EXE folder then the missing DLL is libstdc++-6.dll.

Comment: I should add that I also downloaded Dependency Walker and according to that program there is no dependency on the C and C++ libraries when I compile with the linker options but the dependency DOES show up when I compile without it.  I'm guessing Windows is being dumb but I tried on several different systems and got the same error on all of them.

Comment: could you show us the makefile or the compilation flags dialog's contents?

Comment: I'm not sure where to find the makefile since it seems to be mostly automated by the IDE.  Which compilation dialog are you referring to specifically?  There are several it seems.  Under the C/C++ Build/GCC C++ Compiler/All Options box it has this: -I"C:\\_projects_eclipse\bcsdll\src\" -include"C:\_projects_eclipse\bcsdll\src\bcsdll.h" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0  NOTE that there is actually a \ after -include"C:... which doesn't seem to show up on the site.

Comment: The ones passed to the linker. Also some elaboration on " the compiler can't find my simple DLL." would be helpful.

Comment: Well, that's not the primary issue.  That was an aside in case it might be related.  What I'm trying to resolve is why even though I'm statically including the C and C++ libraries that when I run the program I'm still getting the error that the libraries are not available.

Comment: Here are the linker options being used: g++ "-LC:\\_projects_eclipse\\bcsdll\\Debug" -Wl,-enable-stdcall-fixup -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o bcsdll_tester.exe Main.o -lbcsdll

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally solved this. I switched to using -static without the specific -static-libgcc and -static-libstdc++ options. When I did that my EXE compile started giving me errors that it couldn't find my hellodll even though it was still in the same place. Some more Googling and I found that I needed to be compiling the library to end up with .a or .so instead of .dll. Poking around in Eclipse CDT I found under the C/C++ Build/Settings/Build Artifact tab that the Artifact Type was set to "Shared Library". I switched that to static library, compiled the DLL, recompiled the EXE, and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

useful to windows users who use eclipse for c/c++ but run *.exe file and get an error: "missing libstdc++6.dll"

4 ways to solve it

1. Eclipse ->"Project" -> "Properties" -> "C/C++ Build" -> "Settings" -> "Tool Settings" -> "MinGW C++ Linker" -> "Misscellaneous" -> "Linker flags" (add '-static' to it)
2. Add '{{the path where your MinGW was installed}}/bin' to current user environment variable - "Path" in Windows, then reboot eclipse, and finally recompile.
3. Add '{{the path where your MinGW was installed}}/bin' to Windows environment variable - "Path", then reboot eclipse, and finally recompile.
4. Copy the file "libstdc++-6.dll" to the path where the *.exe file is running, then rerun. (this is not a good way)

Note: the file "libstdc++-6.dll" is in the folder '{{the path where your MinGW was installed}}/bin'